# I can't access a servlet when changing localhost for the host public IP

Tags: tomcat, servlets

I'm using Apache Tomcat 7.0.27. I'm just testing [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseWTP/article.html) servlet example tutorial and it runs properly when I launch it on Eclipse, which uses this URL: localhost/xxx/TestServlet. However, if I change localhost with mi (public) IP or the domain I have registered for it, it fails. No matter if I try from the Eclipse-embedded browser or from a stand-alone browser. I've also tried deploying a WAR but it neither works.

I've found some ideas that talk about tweaking the server.xml file on the Apache installation with Connector's and host aliases, but I can't seem to make it work. I don't know what more to try and this is why I post this.

In case it helps to solve my issue, here it goes the server.xml I'm using:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />

    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />

    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
            xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Comment: Can you post the error you usually get if you're connecting to the domain?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the domain inside the `<Host>` example :

```
  <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
        xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
    <Alias>domain.com</Alias>
    <Alias>www.domain.com</Alias>

    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

  </Host>
```

Normally, it will do the trick!